# Хром печать всплывающего окна, вешает окно родитель

Tags: google-chrome, window.open, javascript

Собственно проблема:

```
                if( jQuery(e.target).hasClass('show_image')){
                    $.fancybox.open([
                        {
                        type : 'image',
                            href : jQuery(e.target).attr('rel'),
                            title : 'Карта проезда'
                        }]);
var win=null;
var content = $('.fancybox-inner');
var text = $(e.target).parent().parent().find('.text_detal');

$('.fancybox-wrap').append('<div id="fancy_print"></div>').on("click", "#fancy_print",function(){
  win = window.open("","","");
  self.focus();
  win.document.open();
  win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'head'+'><'+'style'+'>');
  win.document.write('body, td { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;}');
  win.document.write('<'+'/'+'style'+'><'+'/'+'head'+'><'+'body'+'>');
  win.document.write(content.html());
  win.document.write('<hr />');
  win.document.write(text.html());
  win.document.write('<'+'/'+'body'+'><'+'/'+'html'+'>');
  win.document.close();
  win.print();
  win.close();
});

                    return false;
                }
```

В общем я здесь открываю fancybox окно, вешаю на него кнопочку которая будет печатать определенный контент. Карту и адрес.

Окно открывается, и печатается. Но... В общем если в хроме нажать на иконку принтера и появится новая вкладка и окно печати. Но если не нажимать на печать или отмену а именно закрыть кладку. Считай все, окно с картой "зависает". Точнее перестает правильно работать, если нажать f5 долго грузится, если нажать на закрытие fancybox надо несклько раз закрывать и все-равно ничего не работает. Для наглядности покажу где это.

http://www.macr.ru/contacts/samara.php#samara

вот там есть карта если на нее нажать появляется картинка, если нажать на иконку принтера ниже справа появится окно.

Причину я понимаю. Не срабатывает win.close().

Как справится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, это баг хрома c 34 версии (вроде), недавно тикет им ставили: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359627